# how make duplicate of an specific file in wordpress media library programatically

Tags: php, wordpress, media-library

I programatically uploaded some files to wordpress media library by this function: 
**media_handle_upload**. this function after adding file to media library returns a number called **wordpress_media_attachment_id** . now I have some files in media library via their attachment ids.

now for some reasons, I want to make duplicate of them programatically.

That means I want to make a copy of those files with new attachment id.

now please give me a snippet code ?

Comment: Well, SO is not your free coding service. Maybe you want to read again [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally solved my problem by this code:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();    
$imgMeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $wordpress_media_attachment_id );
$imgMime = $imgMeta['sizes']['thumbnail']['mime-type'];
$absolutePath = "$wp_upload_dir[basedir]/$imgMeta[file]";

$name = basename($imgMeta['file']);
do{
    $rnd = mt_rand();
    $name2 = "_$rnd$name";
    $path2 = "$wp_upload_dir[path]/$name2";
} while (file_exists($path2));
@copy($absolutePath,$path2);

$attachment = array(
        'guid'=> "$wp_upload_dir[url]/$name2", 
        'post_mime_type' => $imgMime,
        'post_title' => $name2,
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$image_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $path2);
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $image_id, $path2 );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $image_id, $attach_data );
```

and finally I have a new duplicated file with new attachment id called **$image_id**